# Python Regex: Select everything between two brackets ignore brackets in between

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, regex

I want to capture the entire sub-query irrespective of whether there's a concat or substring function in between (i.e. ignore another bracket opening and closing within sub-query. (a) We don't want to capture "join" as a word (b) "alias2" will not always be followed by "join" it can be anything (a word boundary, space, or "join" word).

*Case 1: No concat or sub-string function in select*

- **In:** `(select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2 join`
- **Out:**  `(select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2`

*Case 2: Concat function in select*

- **In:** `(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2 join`
- **Out:**  `(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2`

*What I have tried:*

Approach 1: `re.findall('\(select.*?\)\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', input statement)`

Approach 2: As suggested by @TheFourthBird

```
import re
pat1 = '\(select.*?\)\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'
pat2 = "\(select [^()]*(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)))?[^()]*\)[^()\n]+"

string1 = "(select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2"
string2 = "(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2"

print(re.findall(pat1, string1))
print(re.findall(pat1, string2))

import regex as re
print(re.findall(pat2, string1))
print(re.findall(pat2, string2))

pattern = re.compile(pat2, re.UNICODE)
print([match.group(0) for match in pattern.finditer(string2)])
```

Output:

```
["(select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2"]
['(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as']
['']
['(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1)']
["(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2 join "]
```

*What's wrong with the above approach:*

- Approach 1: Works very well for case 1 but doesn't for case 2.
- Approach 2: Still doesn't work! However, `["(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2 join "]` is the most closet to what's expected. However, it shouldn't capture what's next to alias2.

Please help me!

Comment: Did you install or have you installed https://pypi.org/project/regex/ ?

Comment: See [this example code](https://tio.run/##tZFNb4MwDIbPy6@wcmncAhrtaUgM7bjLdl/TTSkNJRIkKJh9af@dUT6k/YDOB@u19Pi1ZTdfVDq763tTN84TeH3Wn6DaQTDWKCLtLaTguRStrnROsH8VeFiLLBFSiOx@LDc/IosR1xIRswmQKNu9Cr8fwpfb8O7tsOGMtYOT4I82gcWM4ih3VXwZqCqj2hgK72o4HSM6wkepvV6QdPWuqniFE7eVVlrObvhzR1d0@7ta7myuSMwNAdB2EbtR4JWW/pc5HBmrFeWlvtzc66gw9mSGZ4r5pwG0A1I4DyP21NXBpMBY0LartVekxewx0KQ8pTEmDIYYU@ONpYmIzt51jUDs@18)

Comment: yes. Have it installed. however, idea is not to extract only ```(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1)``` but everything.

Comment: The example code matches what you want from the example data, it that not the expected?

Comment: I used the pattern which you shared. It gives me ```['(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1)']``` as output for case 2 and ```['']``` for case 1.

Comment: My guess is that you use regex.findall ? That will give back the value of the captured group. That is why in the example code I have used regex.finditer to get the whole match.

Comment: Updated my approach based on what you suggested. Doesn't work. please see.

Comment: Do you must use re.findall? It works with re.finditer...

Comment: Updated the question. We're most closest with your approach (upvote). However, we don't want to capture anything after the "alias2" word and it will not be "alias2".

Comment: You have an older version of the pattern that I suggested, it should be [like this](https://tio.run/##vZBPT4NAEMXvfIoJl860hXTpSZNKjHrwoicvAjVbusAa2N0s69/43REoGM8evL2ZvPm9yTMfrtJq23WyMdo6sMLzDHcR7MBPsRW1yB0ke6RsifE5pojxxTiuvjBmRMuUiOKTIaW0TXjweRk8boKzp2zle17rrFQlG3AzzbEw1zUD3gKvJW8ZFFY3cDyE7gBvlbBituwWr7xmCzr5InjWUvkTMvqNzLXKucPpbA0umsV2FPTnMO@nl1K8D5SpICes6j@wor9tjKwFDq2th8XD3e3V/fUNeab/02HScJdXYWn1i8ENQaEtjCuQCiZSWEh1lL3CqS/K6B9ioj6m674B) `\(select [^()]*(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)))?[^()]*\)\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

Comment: it's not about the older version. Pattern has changed!! Let me see if it works now.

Comment: Works now for the above example using the pattern you suggested now. Thanks @Thefourthbird.

Comment: You tagged this with both [mysql] and [python].  If this will be used in MySQL, then which version; 8.0 does things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first match `(select`  and optionally match balanced parenthesis using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

At the end of the pattern, match a whitespace char and using your character class.

```
\(select [^()]*(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)))?[^()]*\)\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\(select`  Match `(select`
- `[^()]*` optionally match any char except `(` and `)`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)` Match `(` and use a recursive pattern recursing the first subgroup (capture group 1) and finally match the  `)`
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `[^()]*\)` Optionally match any char except parenthesis, then match `)`
- `\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` Match a whitespace char and 1+ of the listed in the character class

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRCOhu/1/) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##vZBPT4NAEMXvfIoJl860hXTpSZNKjHrwoicvAjVbusAa2N0s69/43REoGM8evL2ZvPm9yTMfrtJq23WyMdo6sMLzDHcR7MBPsRW1yB0ke6RsifE5pojxxTiuvjBmRMuUiOKTIaW0TXjweRk8boKzp2zle17rrFQlG3AzzbEw1zUD3gKvJW8ZFFY3cDyE7gBvlbBituwWr7xmCzr5InjWUvkTMvqNzLXKucPpbA0umsV2FPTnMO@nl1K8D5SpICes6j@wor9tjKwFDq2th8XD3e3V/fUNeab/02HScJdXYWn1i8ENQaEtjCuQCiZSWEh1lL3CqS/K6B9ioj6m674B)

For example, using re.finditer *(as re.findall returns the capture group values)*:

```
import regex as re

pattern = r"\(select [^()]*(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)))?[^()]*\)\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"

s = ("In: (select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2\n\n"
    "Out: (select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2\n\n"
    "In: (select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2\n\n"
    "Out: (select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2\n")

matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print(match.group())
```

Output

```
["(select t1.col1 as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2"]
["(select concat(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1) as alias1 from db.tb where t1.col1='val1') alias2"]
```

**Note** that matching SQL is error prone.